# Верстка, неправильная работа прокрутки страницы сайта на IOS

Tags: html, css, ios, браузер, safari

Есть сайт, который работает хорошо на компьютере и (в том числе в браузере Safari на Mac OS). Но на айфоне происходят проблемы:

- Верхнее меню прокручивается за пределы видимости окна браузера, хотя должно всегда отображаться на компьютере:
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Если прокрутить страницу до конца или открыть меню и прокрутить страницу вниз появляется пустое пространство:
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Некоторые страницы прокручиваются до конца только 1 раз, затем нижняя часть обрезается браузером:
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для создания интерфейса используется angular material, кастомизированный через CSS.

Проблемный сайт можно открыть по ссылке http://octavo.by/ , все ошибки можно увидеть на странице помощи. Подскажите пожалуйста как мне исправить верстку для IOS

Comment: для начала исправьте ошибки, которые вылезают в консоли - возможно, из-за них появляются баги (в любом случае ошибок в консоли быть не должно)

Comment: @humster_spb там ошибки только на главной странице внутри фрейма

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то в сафари появляется панель снизу и закрывает меню в нижней части страницы. В этом случае я добавил бы для сафари отступ снизу на высоту вылезаемой панели